# Does the braid group $B_3$ have a presentation based entirely upon the Dehornoy order?

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

> Does the braid group have a presentation based entirely upon the Dehornoy order?

Let $B_n$ be the braid group $B_3$ for now.

Let $\leq$ be the Dehornoy order on the group

The let $P_i(x,y,z,\ldots)$ be $i$ distinct predicates of the form $ x_i^{p_i}\cdot y_i^{q_i}\ldots\leq z_i^{r_i}\ldots$ where $x,y,z\ldots\in B_n$

Does the Braid group $B_3$ have a presentation $B_n=\langle x,y,z,\ldots\mid P_0\land\ldots P_i \rangle$

More generally I am asking whether the presentation of a group can be entirely order-theoretical.

[More Generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473684/)

Comment: I've never seen the notion of presentation of ordered groups including relators of the form $x_i\le y_i$. A presentation makes sense in the context of universal algebra, which does not encompass such things as orderings. I have no idea what it could be. Model theory has the right language to consider such predicates, but there are no well-defined "free  objects" and "presentations" in such contexts.

Comment: @YCor reflecting on your comment I wonder whether ordinals can provide suitably free objects with respect to order?

Comment: I'd suggest to write down what it means and conclude...